# Typescript conflict with a generic extending a default type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

edit: link to playground https://tsplay.dev/NBJ0zN

i'm creating a hook that is supposed to return a modal component, the hook can take a generic to add some extra typings to the body component i inject inside this hook

i have 2 types that look somewhat like this :

```
export type DefaultBodyComponentProps= {   onClose: ()=> void; };
```

the onClose funcion comes from inside the hook

```
export type ConnectModalConfig<B extends object> = {
  bodyComponent?: React.ComponentType<B & DefaultBodyProps>;
};
```

the modal component returned by this hook is supposed to take an object called bodyProps with some props i can inject inside the body component

```
export type ModalProps<B> = {   bodyProps?: B; };
```

the way i use this hook is like this

```
const [Modal, modalActions] = useConnectedModal<BodyProps>({
  bodyComponent: Body,
});
```

and the modal component

`<Modal bodyProps={..somePropsOfTypeBodyProps}/>`

the modal component inside the hook looks like this

```
export default function useConnectedModal<B extends object = object>(
  props: ConnectModalConfig<B>,
) {
  const { bodyComponent: BodyComponent = DefaultBodyComponent } = props;
  //logic
  const Modal = (props: ModalProps<B>) => {
    const { bodyProps } = props;
    const onClose = () => {
      //logic
    };
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <BodyComponent {...bodyProps} onClose={onClose} />{' '}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  };
  return [Modal];
}
```

but i get this typescript error that says :

`Type '{ onClose: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'B'.   '{ onClose: () => void; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'B', but 'B' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'.`

I understand what it means but i can't seem to be able to solve it xD

Any tips ?

Comment: This is not a minimal reproducible example. We're missing a lot of definitions: https://tsplay.dev/w25jbW

Comment: ops my bad https://tsplay.dev/NBJ0zN

Comment: The " sad thing " is that this seems to be working as intended i just can't get rid of that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i solved it by casting bodyProps as B

```
<BodyComponent {...bodyProps as B} onClose={onClose} />
```

not important to my question but i also ended up wanting bodyProps to stay optional so i did this utility type

```
type RequirePropsIfAdditionalPropsExist<T, T2 extends string> = keyof Omit<
  T,
  'onClose'
> extends never
  ? { [K in T2]?: never }
  : { [K in T2]: Omit<T, 'onClose'> };


export type ModalProps<B, F, H> = RequirePropsIfAdditionalPropsExist<
  B,
  'bodyProps'
> &
  RequirePropsIfAdditionalPropsExist<H, 'headerProps'> &
  RequirePropsIfAdditionalPropsExist<F, 'footerProps'> & {
    onClose?: OnClose;
  };
```

that way when i call the component if i passed something else in the generic other than onClose ts will give me a warning

Answer (score 0):

replace `ModalProps` with: (remove the `?`)

```
export type ModalProps<B> = { bodyProps: B; };
```

and it seems like everything is fine.

---

The error shows because if `bodyProps` is optional and not provided, there will no `B` pass into the component

Comment: This works but i wanted the bodyProps to be optional, i solved it casting it as B

<BodyComponent {...bodyProps as B} onClose={onClose} />{' '}